# Forked and Customize the 3rd Party React Component not working in react js

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, git-fork

I have forked https://github.com/naisutech/react-tree plugin and did some custom changes in UI. Then I am trying to add my forked plugin in my react js app like this

```
npm i https://github.com/myRepo/react-tree
```

node_modules also updated.
But, its show **Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-tree'** error. package.json it's updated correctly. don't know what exactly I missed to add a forked plugin add to my project. Please help me on this guys.

Comment: You need to push production build to Github repo.

Comment: @NageshDhope you mean that forked Github repo. this one github.com/myRepo/react-tree?

Comment: Yes, the forked one.